# SonicWALL SSL VPN Can't Click Bookmarks

Tags: security, vpn, sonicwall

I've added an RDP bookmark to my SSL VPN Virtual Office page, but can't click it. I've tried importing the certificate, adding to Trusted Sites, and setting Security to Low....but the bookmark just doesn't appear as a hyperlink for some reason. Screenshot below. Notice it's not a hyperlink and thus not clickable.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this recently, having never seen this behavior on several SonicWALL devices that I've configured over the years. The details in this article resolved the issue for me: https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170505310636560

To summarize: In the *Client Settings* configuration for the SSL VPN I found that an "Unknown" IPv4 address range was assigned. I assigned an IPv4 address range and found that the Virtual Office Bookmarks became usable.

Answer (score 1):

Is the SonicWall able to resolve "dc1" IP address? You can test that by using the "Diagnostic page" of the appliance, under "Status menu"

Comment: Diagnostic page does not allow me to select X0 as the interface IP. How can I verify?

Comment: In the diagnostic page you can find a drop box to select the tool to use. Both a simple ping or a name resolution test will serve you; simply ignore the interface selection box. Anyway, you really had to read the manual...

Comment: What are you talking about "read the manual"? I've read it. This behavior isn't described anywhere. No, it can't resolve the name...but it's set to the wrong interface...

Comment: Read the manual because you can't use the debug tool. Moreover, your service is incapable of DNS resolving, so it is clearly misconfigured.